# Is it possible to install a docker container on a virtual Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, virtualization, docker

Is it possible to install docker.io on an Ubuntu server in a virtual environment?

Maybe on the vserver of a hosting provider?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is completely possible and people do it all the time. For example you can run it on Linode using the guide here https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/docker

The same guide should apply to any distro and any VPS Provider.